# Bounded above set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\phi:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function where for every $A, B\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $A\cap B=\varnothing$, $\phi(A\cup B)=\phi(A)+\phi(B)$. I want to prove that the following set is bounded above.

$\left\{ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\phi(A_i)|;\;A_1,\dots,A_n\; \text{are two to two disjoint}\right\}$,

I don't know if I need another condition.

Comment: Your condition is odd.  Say $A=B\neq \emptyset$.  Then $A\cap B=A\neq \emptyset$.  Would you then conclude that $\phi(A)=\phi(A\cup A)=2\phi(A)$?  If so, then $\phi(A)=0$ for every non-empty $A$.

Comment: Can you edit your post for clarity?  The thing you are trying to prove is true for any real valued function $\phi$.  After all, it's a finite sum of real numbers, and all such are finite.  What are you asking?

Comment: @lulu A set of finite numbers need not be bounded above in general. Am I missing something that makes it obviously true in this case?

Comment: @Bungo  oh, you think he means the set of all such sums?  Maybe you are right about that.

Comment: Isn't it a set, each element of which is a finite sum of real numbers?

Comment: @Bungo  Yeah, I revised my comment after I realized he might mean that.  But, of course,  the claim isn't true with that interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

Use the axiom of choice.  There is an additive function $\psi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ not of the form $\psi(x) = ax$ for a constant $a$.  **Additive** means
$$
\psi(x+y) = \psi(x)+\psi(y)\qquad\text{for all } x,y \in \mathbb R .
$$
For the existence, see [Cauchy's Functional Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).
Such a weird function $\psi$ must satisfy: $\psi$ is unbounded (both above and below) on $[0,1]$.  [Indeed, $\psi$ is unbounded on any nonempty open set.]
Now define our set-function $\phi : \mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to \mathbb R$ using the binary expansion.  That is, for any set $A$, let
$$
\phi(A) = \psi\left(\sum_{j \in A} 2^{-j}\right) .
$$

Now we claim $\phi$ has the additive property specified.  Indeed, suppose $A \cap B = \varnothing$.  Then the addition of
$$
\sum_{j \in A} 2^{-j} \qquad \text{and}\qquad \sum_{j \in B} 2^{-j}
$$
takes place with no carrying, so
$$
\sum_{j \in A} 2^{-j} +\sum_{j \in B} 2^{-j} = \sum_{j \in A \cup B} 2^{-j}
$$
and thus
$$
\phi(A)+\phi(B) =
\psi\left(\sum_{j \in A} 2^{-j}\right) +\psi\left(\sum_{j \in B} 2^{-j}\right)
= \psi\left(\sum_{j \in A \cup B} 2^{-j}\right) = \phi(A \cup B) .
$$

Now what about the boundedness claimed for the conclusion?  In fact, since $\psi$ is unbounded on $[0,1]$, even using a single set at a time gives us something unbounded:
$$
\sup\left\{\phi(A) : A \in \mathcal P(\mathbb N)\right\} \ge 
\sup\left\{\psi(x) : x \in [0,1]\right\}
= +\infty
$$
(Note that if $x \in (0,1)$ is a number with two different binary expansions, then it is listed twice in the right-hand set.)

Comment: I understand. I was confused about this because I want to prove that the function "norm" in $ba(\mathbb{N})$ is well defined.